# Convert object containing 2D object array into string array

Tags: c#

I have a method which returns the following type and object:

```
object {object[,]}
test    {object[19, 2]}
```

Is it possible to convert this into 2d string array, or a datatable?

Comment: so... did it help or not?

Answer (score 0):

Looks akward, but I haven't found another way.

```
int firstDimensionSize = 19;
int secondDimensionSize = 2;

object[,] objectArray = new object[firstDimensionSize, secondDimensionSize];

string[,] stringArray = new string[objectArray.Length / secondDimensionSize, secondDimensionSize];

for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.Length / secondDimensionSize; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < secondDimensionSize; j++)
    {
        stringArray[i, j] = objectArray[i, j].ToString();
    }
}
```

In case your second dimension is always the same you could leave out the inner loop, replacing it with static code.

See also https://www.dotnetperls.com/2d

Answer (score 0):

I made this extension method, but you can aswell make it a normal method if you don't need it that often.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string[,] ConvertToString2D(this object[,] arr)
    {
        int dim1 = arr.GetLength(0);
        int dim2 = arr.GetLength(1);
        string[,] strArray = new string[dim1, dim2];

        for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++)
            {
                strArray[i, j] = Convert.ToString(arr[i, j]);
            }
        }

        return strArray;
    }
}
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
var result = objArr.ConvertToString2D();
```